# Python: sorting Intervals with __cmp__, with __lt__ meaning "strictly less than"

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, operators

I have an [`intervaltree`](https://github.com/chaimleib/intervaltree) library that needs to sort `Intervals` and eventually `Points`.

I have a `__cmp__` method that imposes very stable and logical sorting (see end for the code). And, I have a useful `__lt__` method for seeing if intervals are strictly less than each other (ditto).

I have about 30 tests for this behavior, and this is going fine...

## The problem

...Except when I have to sort:

```
>>> sorted([Interval(0, 10), Interval(-10, 5)])
[Interval(0, 10), Interval(-10, 5)]               # WRONG!
```

Because Python uses `__lt__`, it uses "strictly less-than" semantics instead of `__cmp__`. I can force it to do that explicitly, but I'd rather avoid the cumbersome syntax:

```
>>> sorted([Interval(0, 10), Interval(-10, 5)], cmp=Interval.__cmp__)
[Interval(-10, 5), Interval(0, 10)]               # RIGHT
```

In Python 3, the syntax is even more cumbersome (not available in Python 2.6, available in Python 2.7).

```
>>> from functools import cmp_to_key
>>> sorted([Interval(0, 10), Interval(-10, 5)], key=cmp_to_key(Interval.__cmp__))
```

### What I want

Is there a way I can make `sorted()` and friends use `Interval.__cmp__` automatically, but still keep `__lt__` as-is? That is, I want this elegant behavior:

```
>>> sorted([Interval(0, 10), Interval(-10, 5)])   # no extra arguments!
[Interval(-10, 5), Interval(0, 10)]
```

## Appendix: Implementations for `__cmp__` and `__lt__`

```
def __cmp__(self, other):
    """
    Tells whether other sorts before, after or equal to this
    Interval.

    Sorting is by begins, then by ends, then by data fields.

    If data fields are not both sortable types, data fields are
    compared alphabetically by type name.
    :param other: Interval
    :return: -1, 0, 1
    :rtype: int
    """
    s = self[0:2]
    try:
        o = other[0:2]
    except:
        o = (other,)
    if s != o:
        return -1 if s < o else 1
    try:
        if self.data == other.data:
            return 0
        return -1 if self.data < other.data else 1
    except TypeError:
        s = type(self.data).__name__
        o = type(other.data).__name__
        if s == o:
            return 0
        return -1 if s < o else 1

def __lt__(self, other):
    """
    Less than operator. Returns False if there is an overlap.
    :param other: Interval or point
    :return: True or False
    :rtype: bool
    """
    return not self.overlaps(other) and self.end <= other
```

PS: This problem is in the development branch, where I want to change `__lt__`'s behavior to "strictly less-than." In the master branch (release 1.1.0), `__lt__` just parrots `__cmp__`.

## Update

- (2014-12-12):
  Right now in my develop branch, I'm providing `Interval.sorted` and `Interval.key`. Still not so elegant, though. I'm still looking for a better way!

Comment: The only way to get what you ask for is stack inspection using the `inspect` module. To tell if `__lt__` is being called due to a comparison done by `sorted`, and then to behave differently if it is. It would work but it could be slow.

Comment: Wow. That's an interesting hack. It's one of those moments: "I would use this ring from a desire to do good... But through me, it would wield a power too great and terrible to imagine." ;)

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest **against defining *any* of the order operators** for your class.

The reason is that existence of the order operators implies an order-relation exists, along with its associated semantics, which your class inherently violates (there is no well-defined order relation on intervals).

For example, an order-relation implies that:

```
not(a<b) and not(b<a) ==> a==b
```

This is not true for intervals.

In other words, you shouldn't just decide what you want your operators to mean (e.g. that `__lt__` means *strict* less-than), the semantics is predfined in the languauge for you (e.g. the implementation of `sorted` relies on that semantics).

What you should do is define non-operator methods for comparing (e.g. `def strict_lt(self, other): ...`), and use them. I'd also define a `sort_intervals` function, and use it in your code instead of `sorted` directly. E.g.:

```
def sort_intervals(lst):
    return sorted(lst, cmp = ...)
```

Comment: First, thanks for the reply!

I think it will take some time for me, for this philosophy to sink in.

In the meantime, I have added a custom `sorted()` method. Since Python3 does not support `sorted(..., cmp=...)` but only `sorted(..., key=...)` I had to make a custom `key()` method.